# Adding a javascript virtual joystick to ionic 3

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I would like to use [NippleJS virtual joystick](https://github.com/yoannmoinet/nipplejs) in my Ionic 3 project. I first installed the library using `npm install nipplejs --save`. Then, I added some stuff to my .html and .ts files as follows.

HTML:

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar>
    <ion-title>
      Test Virtual Joystick
    </ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content padding>

  <div id="zone_joystick"></div>

</ion-content>
```

TS

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { nipplejs } from 'nipplejs'

@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {
    var options = {
        zone: document.getElementById('zone_joystick')
    };

    var manager = nipplejs.create(options);
  }    
}
```

However, I get `Cannot read property 'create' of undefined TypeError`. How should I handle this?

Comment: https://github.com/yoannmoinet/nipplejs/issues/21 check this out

Comment: No idea about the nipplejs thing, but `zone_joystick` will for sure be undefined in the constructor. That needs to be in another lifecycle callback, most likely `ngAfterViewInit`. where the DOM already had been created.

Comment: I added a starter project ["vjstarter on github"](https://github.com/ahmadi86/vjstarter)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like `nippleJS` is not built on the ES2015 standard, so you'll need to import it like this:

First, install it: `npm install nipplejs --save`

Then import it like this

`import nipplejs from 'nipplejs';`

and use it

`nipplejs.create(...);`

**EDIT**

Just like @Matthias247 mentioned in his comment, since you need to include an element from the DOM in the options, you should place that code in the `ionViewDidLoad` lifecycle hook (the DOM is not ready yet when the constructor is executed):

```
ionViewDidLoad() {

  // Now we know the DOM is ready
  let options = {
    zone: document.getElementById('zone_joystick')
  };

  let manager = nipplejs.create(options);

}
```